# css - can i insert another a class/id when i trigger a hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

Hello i have a code like this

```
<button type="button" class="button2">PROVIDER PORTAL</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a class="btn btn-info button2s" href="applicationprovider.aspx">APPLY AS PROVIDER</a>
   <a class="btn btn-info button2s" href="loginProvider.aspx">LOGIN TO ACCOUNT</a>
</div>
```

What is happening in my css is when I hover the `button2` this css is triggered

```
.button2:hover {
   background-color: #286090;
   color: #f5f9fc;
   border-color: #f5f9fc;
}
```

then this
 `<div class='dropdown-content'` will trigger and open up a new selection for the `<a>`'s like this

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
   transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
}
```

i want to retain the color of the `.button2` while im still hovering the `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`. in this question, I want the `.button2:hover { }` to be retained while i still hover the `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content`

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery

**Jquery**

```
$("#button1").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("but1");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("but1");
});
$("#button2").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("but2");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("but2");
});
```

Comment: I'll try this later Nevermore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could nest your elements, which *should* allow you to achieve the styling that you desire without having to use JS/jQuery to add & remove classes.

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="title">Provider Portal</span>
  <div class="dropdown">
    Dropdown content
  </div>
</div>
```

Then

```
<style>
.title { // title can be styled like a button
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #286090;
  color: white; }
.dropdown { // hide dropdown content
  display: none; }
.container:hover .title, .title:hover { // retain hover color
  background: lightblue; }
.container:hover .dropdown { // show dropdown content
  display: block; }
</style>
```

See my example here https://jsfiddle.net/dxg1v7rv/